# $\frac{d}{dr}=0$ and $\frac{d}{dz}=0$ (cylindrical coordinates) for a 1D ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coordinate-systems, differentiation

In

http://ritchie.chem.ox.ac.uk/Grant%20Teaching/2010/Lecture%204%202010.pdf

slide 21 of 26, he says  "Radius of ring is fixed and so derivatives
in $r$ are 0."  Presumably this goes for $\frac{d}{dz}$ too.

But for points on the ring, as you step on/off the ring, aren't
you transitioning from some non-zero value of the wave function,
to 0  (since the wave function is 0 everywhere
off the ring)  so the slope
is infinite?

--

(note:  the .pdf is  "The Quantum Theory of Atoms and Molecules:
particles in boxes and applications,"
by Dr.Grant Ritchie, 26 slides.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general this sort of double-speak is very common.

What he really means is something more like: "We want to consider only the angular part of the cylindrical Schrodinger equation, and the proper limit to take here is to send $\nabla^2 \mapsto r^{-2}~\partial_\phi^2.$ We know that is proper because if $\partial_r$ and $\partial_z$ were zero and hence irrelevant, then that would be the only term of $\nabla^2$ that would be left."

Comment: Thanks!   I want to be sure
I understand you so I will repeat back in my own words.
The Schrödinger equation is known to be applicable
in 3-D space for any mutually orthogonal set of 3 axes,
that is each of the 3 axes can be solved separately.
$x y z$ or $\rho \phi z$ or $\theta \phi r$ or what have you.
Thus, since by definition of the problem the electron
is localized to the 1-D ring, we can just go down to
1-D space of unit vector $\hat{\phi}$, just as for
particle in a box you can extrapolate up an $x$-dimension
only solution up to 3-D usefully.

Comment: It took me a second to see what you're saying but that's definitely another way to think of it. Yes, if we were doing this in bona-fide 3D, via $-\nabla^2\psi + u(r, z) \psi = \eta \psi,$ we would probably use our standard partial differential equation trick, which is a [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables), $\psi=R(r)~\Phi(\phi)~Z(z).$ Then the equation for $\phi$ drops out nicely with $\Phi''(\phi) = \alpha~\Phi$ contributing a term $\alpha\psi/r^2$ to $\nabla^2\psi,$ building up the 3D solution from this 1D solution if we divide $\alpha$ by $r^2.$

Comment: I guess this is what we are implicitly doing in 1D
particle in a box too:
potential energy $V$ is infinite in all the y and z  (the other two dimensions).